# Looping through all subdirectories & contents in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, compression, python-imaging-library

I need to loop through all current/input directory and open all images with validated extensions and reduce their file sizes, I know it can be done using python pillow library:

```
for image in imgs:
   img = Image.open(image)
   image.save(image,quality=0,optimize=True)
```

Comment: Ugh! Looks to me like that is not a very good idea to go around overwriting all my precious photos with poor quality versions. And, if that is really your aim, you can do it much more simply, and specify a different output directory with **ImageMagick** as follows `mogrify -quality 0 -path lowquality *png *jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell it's for situations that you want to fix another person code and you look and all images which they are stored in their original size. I agree with you about bringing down the quality though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using glob and os, os.path.

below script will read your current directory path and will loop through its subdirectories and open all images which are validated and then reduce their file size approximate to 50% of their original file size:

```
import glob
import Image
import os, os.path

img_gallery_path = raw_input("Enter image gallery directory path like image/user:  ")

imgs = []
path = img_gallery_path
valid_images = [".jpg",".gif",".png",".jpeg"]

for f in os.listdir(path):
    ext = os.path.splitext(f)[1]
    name = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
    if ext.lower() not in valid_images:
        continue
    img=Image.open(os.path.join(path,f))
    img.save(img_gallery_path+name+ext.lower(),quality=0,optimize=True)
```

Hope to save others time.